Free group on $X$ means no relation in $X^{\pm}$
I am reading Free Groups from the book ``Presentations of Groups" by D. L. Johnson.

The author says that the existence of $\theta'$ means there is no relation in $X^{\pm}$. He gives the argument for it in Remark  1(i) above. I am not able to understand how one can find a group $G$ with the corresponding elements (under $\theta$) for which that relation does not hold.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Let's see how an example works. Take $X=\{a,b\}$ so we are looking at the free group on two generators. We may pick a specific relation to get the hang of things. Let's take for example $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ (or $ab=ba$)i.e. we are are looking at the free abelian group on two generators and consider the map $\theta: X\rightarrow S_5$ by $\theta(a)=(1\quad 2)$ and $\theta (b)=(2 \quad 3)$. Suppose there exists a $\theta': F_2\rightarrow S_5$, homomorphism. Then we would have:
$$
e_{S_5}=\theta'(aba^{-1}b^{-1})=\theta'(a)\theta'(b)\theta'(a^-1)\theta'(b^{-1})=(1\quad 2)(2\quad 3)(1\quad 2)(2\quad 3)=(1\quad 3\quad 2) 
$$
So by using the fact that $\theta'$ is a homomorpish we arrive to a contradiction. The idea is that since we picked the abelianazation relation we used a non abelian group so we are always looking for a group that a given relation doesn't hold in. Can you see how to extend this idea to a proof ?

I understand the abelian case but what about the random words $w$ and $w'$ with $w=w'$.

Then you would just pick your favorite group G generated also by X (or by a set with the same cardinality of X) that does not contain that word. You want to use the fact that $\theta'$ is a homomorphism, so if $x_1^{a_1}\ldots x_n^{a_n}=e$ then $(\theta'(x_1))^{a_1}\ldots(\theta'(x_n))^{a_n}=e$

Also note that a relation $w=w'$ implies that $w'w^{-1}=e$

Do you mean that I should consider the free group on $X$ and quotient it by a normal subgroup generated by the relation $w=w'$. This will give me a group in which this relation does not hold.

@LoveMath the relation would hold in that quotient, but not in the free group on $X$.

I am still confused. How can one guarantee that given any two words $w$ and $w'$ there exists a group in which this relation ($w=w'$) does not hold?

@LoveMath If $G$ is the usual construction of the free group on $X$ (via words in $X^{\pm}$), by definition if $w$ and $w'$ are distinct words in $X^{\pm}$, they are not equal in $G$.

Let $G$ be the group whose elements are reduced words in the alphabet $X^{\pm}$, with multiplication given by concatenation and reduction of words (i.e. the usual construction of a free group), and let $\theta: X \to G$ be the inclusion map.
A "relation" in $F$ could mean an equality
$$\mathrm{inc}(x_1)^{\epsilon_1}\mathrm{inc}(x_2)^{\epsilon_2} \cdots \mathrm{inc}(x_n)^{\epsilon_n} = \mathrm{inc}(y_1)^{\kappa_1} \mathrm{inc}(y_2)^{\kappa_2} \cdots \mathrm{inc}(y_m)^{\kappa_m} \tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$ in $F$, where the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are elements of $X$ and the $\epsilon_i$ and $\kappa_i$ are $\pm 1$, such that
$$\theta(x_1)^{\epsilon_1} \theta(x_2)^{\epsilon_2} \cdots \theta(x_n)^{\epsilon_n} \neq \theta(y_1)^{\kappa_1}\theta(y_2)^{\kappa_2} \cdots \theta(y_m)^{\kappa_m} \tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$
in $G$.
However, applying $\theta'$ to both sides of $(\clubsuit)$ immediately contradicts $(\diamondsuit)$.
